# C++ Connector : Inserting datetime with MariaDB

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to insert datetime from a C++ application to a MariaDB server via the C++-connector:

```
MYSQL_TIME  ts;
MYSQL_TIME *timestamps[]= {&ts};
char timestamps_ind[]= {STMT_INDICATOR_NTS};
bind[1].buffer= timestamps;
bind[1].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_DATETIME;
bind[1].u.indicator= timestamps_ind;

ts.year = 2020;
ts.month = 3;
ts.day = 19;
ts.hour = 8;
ts.minute = 5;
```

After executing this is sending NULL to the DateTime column. If I change `bind[1].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP;` to `MYSQL_TYPE_DATE` it sends the correct values to the database, but because of DATE only the year-month-day.

Is there anything I miss to send this as DateTime?

Comment: MYSQL_TYPE_DATETIME then?

Comment: Buf if I set the `buffer_type` to MYSQL_TIME_DATETIME the result in the database is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
To use datetime I need to set all attributes of MYSQL_TIME. I was missing `second` and `second_part`.